# Date picker dialog shows multiple times

Tags: android

I am creating an android activity which needs to get date from user.My activity has a edit text when it is touched shows the datepicker dialog and shows the date in the edit text.I have completed it by using Datepickerdialog.My problem is when i click the edittext 2 datepickerdialog are shown.

Here is my code...

Activity.class

```
EditText startDate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_event);
    startDate= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startdate);
    startDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            new DatePickerDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),"DatePicker");

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void returnDate(String date) {
    startDate.setText(date);
}
```

DatepickerDialog class

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

TheListener listener;

public interface TheListener{
    public void returnDate(String date);
}
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    listener = (TheListener) getActivity();


    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date=dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
    if(listener!=null)
    {
        listener.returnDate(date);
    }

}
}
```

what is the problem in my code.and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your code like this with `ACTION_UP` motion event

```
 @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    new DatePickerDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(),"DatePicker");                      
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: it works but another problem occures.the month field comes like 33 and does not change after first time

Comment: is it month field coming 33 or day field?

Comment: your code seems ok, dont know why it is showing 33 in month

Comment: I debugg the code untill before `String date=dateFormat.format(c.getTime());` this the month will be correct form this line change the month to 48 or 33 and other no.

Comment: sorry it's my fault it is all because of 'mm' instead of 'MM'

Comment: yes... i was checking it for you and found the same. +1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just adding if condition `hasFocus` then call the method. It solve my problem.

In XML Part: I add property to EditText:

`android:focusable="false"`

In Main Activity under onCreate Method:

```
dateinput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); //keyboard disappear
            dateinput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        showDateDailogForm(dateinput);
                    }
                }
            });
```

In Main Activity outside onCreate Method:

```
    private void showDateDailogForm(final EditText dateinput) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    dateinput.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
                }
            };
            new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dateSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
```