# On touch, date picker appears twice

Tags: java, android, datepicker, touch-event

I am trying to implement date picker in my application. But I am stuck with a problem.

When I am clicking on the text field, the calendar for date picker is appearing twice. How to solve this issue?

Here is the code:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    private Calendar cal;
    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private EditText et_startDate;
    private EditText et_endDate;
    private Button btn_create;
    private EditText et_eventname;
    private EditText et_venue;
    private EditText et_description_new;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    private DatabaseHandler mySQLiteAdapter;
    private Calendar calendar;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID1 = 0;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    Spinner spinner_dept = null;
    String deptId = null;
    List<String> list_dept = null;
    View rootView = null;
    String format = "";
    String strTime = null;

    public EventFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // To connect to database
        mySQLiteAdapter = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);

        btn_create = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_create);
        et_eventname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_eventname);
        et_venue = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_venue);
        et_description_new = (EditText) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.et_description);

        spinner_dept = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dept);
        timePicker = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

        list_dept = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_dept = mySQLiteAdapter.getAllDept();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterDept = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_dept);

        dataAdapterDept
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner_dept.setAdapter(dataAdapterDept);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        et_startDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dp_startdate);
        et_startDate.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

                return true;
            }
        });



        et_endDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dp_enddate);
        et_endDate.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectEndDateFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

                return true;
            }
        });

        // Spinner item selection Listener
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

        // Button click Listener
        addListenerOnButton();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {

        spinner_dept
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());

    }

    // get the selected dropdown list value

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner_dept = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_dept);

        btn_create = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_create);

        btn_create.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Toast.makeText(
                // getActivity(),
                // "On Button Click : "
                // + "\n"
                // + String.valueOf(spinner_dept.getSelectedItem()),
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                String deptKey = String.valueOf(spinner_dept.getSelectedItem());
                deptId = mySQLiteAdapter.getDeptId(deptKey);

                String eventname = et_eventname.getText().toString();
                String startdate = et_startDate.getText().toString();
                String enddate = et_endDate.getText().toString();
                String description = et_description_new.getText().toString();
                String venue = et_venue.getText().toString();
                String format = "";

                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                showTime(hour, min);

                String id = null;
                if (eventname.isEmpty()) {
                    alertbox("Event", "Event name not entered");
                } else if (startdate.isEmpty()) {
                    alertbox("Event", "Start date not entered");
                } else if (enddate.isEmpty()) {
                    alertbox("Event", "End date not entered");
                } else if (description.isEmpty()) {
                    alertbox("Event", "Description not entered");
                } else {
                    mySQLiteAdapter = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                    // id = mySQLiteAdapter.createEventid();
                    boolean flag = mySQLiteAdapter.insertEvent(eventname,
                            startdate, enddate, description, venue, strTime,
                            deptId);
                    if (flag == true)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Event Created Successfully",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Event Not Created",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }

            public void showTime(int hour, int min) {
                if (hour == 0) {
                    hour += 12;
                    format = "AM";
                } else if (hour == 12) {
                    format = "PM";
                } else if (hour > 12) {
                    hour -= 12;
                    format = "PM";
                } else {
                    format = "AM";
                }

                StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder().append(hour)
                        .append(" : ").append(min).append(" ").append(format);
                strTime = time.toString();

            }

        });

    }

    // Dialog functionality
    protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(mymessage)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                            }
                        }).show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);

        }

        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            et_startDate.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class SelectEndDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, yy, mm, dd);
        }
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {
            populateSetDate(yy, mm + 1, dd);
        }

        public void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            et_endDate.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [Checkout this answer. It will solve your problem. I had the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670283/5811560)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in the edittext xml

```
android:focusable="false"
```

trade your setOnTouchListener with setOnClickListener

```
    et_startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

        }
    });
```

Comment: I copied what you had inside the setOnTouchListener, I edited the response

Comment: But I want to know why is there a problem on using onTouch